# Adding items to ObservableColletion - UWP C#

Tags: c#, class, uwp, observablecollection

When I'm trying to add items to observable collection, it always replace all items with items added last. What is the reason for it? My code is here

```
  public class FavoriteClassList
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public static ObservableCollection<FavoriteClassList> _FavoriteClassList = new ObservableCollection<FavoriteClassList>();
FavoriteClassList objFavoriteClassList = new FavoriteClassList();

for (int m=1;m<=10;m++)
            {
              objFavoriteClassList.ID = m;
              objFavoriteClassList.Name  = "Name"+m;
             _FavoriteClassList.Add(objFavoriteClassList);
            }
```

Now when printing values of AppGlobals._FavoriteClassList it shows 10 items. But ID and Name of each items is always 10 and Name10 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added one object 10 times and rewrite it 10 times. Here is a fixed version:

```
public class FavoriteClassList
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
public static ObservableCollection<FavoriteClassList> _FavoriteClassList = new ObservableCollection<FavoriteClassList>();


for (int m=1;m<=10;m++)
{
   FavoriteClassList objFavoriteClassList = new FavoriteClassList();
   objFavoriteClassList.ID = m;
   objFavoriteClassList.Name  = "Name"+m;
   _FavoriteClassList.Add(objFavoriteClassList);
}
```